# What is the metadata for "AI Applications" in this deployment error?

Tags: deployment, custom-field, deployment-error

I'm trying to delete some fields from an org, and this error pops up saying that the field is being used somewhere:

> This custom field is referenced elsewhere in salesforce.com.
> AI Applications: Opportunity_Activity

What is this "AI Applications" metadata? Where do I go to remove this field usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attempt to change custom Opportunity Fields field type or delete organizations using Einstein features may see this error 'This custom field is referenced elsewhere in salesforce.com: AI Application'.

To resolve this issue 'Einstein Prediction Builder' should be deleted using below steps.

1. From Setup, enter Einstein Prediction Builder in the Quick Find box, then select Einstein Prediction Builder. Or, on the Einstein Prediction Builder tile in Setup Home, click Get Started.
2. If it’s your first time using Einstein Prediction Builder, click Get Started on the splash page.
3. Delete existing Einstein Predictions.
4. After deleting all existing Einstein Predictions, try deleting field.

Check more details [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000380428&type=1).